# LDAP AD, get password

Tags: java, windows, active-directory, ldap

I need to check user password by LDAP query. I made a quick research in the internet but i cannot find the right answer.

The test server i use: https://www.forumsys.com/tutorials/integration-how-to/ldap/online-ldap-test-server/

I tried query (uid=tesla) in ldapadmin, but i cannot see password parameter

(uid=tesla)

I wanted to get user password, is it possible to do this in LDAP AD ?

Comment: You usually check the password by performing a bind operation against the LDAP server.

Comment: You want to get the pasword why? No competently designed security system will give you the password. Last time I saw that was 1979.

Comment: I need password to update it on another system i mean it will be users migrated 1:1

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. You can *set* the password by using the [`unicodePwd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adls/aa5cb181-d309-4af7-bf3c-77475e0a664b) attribute, but you cannot read it. Active Directory simply does not give you any way to do so.

Even if you could read it, the format would not be in clear text. The documentation (linked above) says that the `unicodePwd` attribute stores:

> The password of the user in Windows NT operating system one-way format (OWF). ...
>
> **Note:** The clear password cannot be derived back from the OWF form of the password.